# Use a Repeater from an Array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arrays, data-binding, repeater

Supposing I have a set of comma separated lists which I need to display into a `Repeater`, how would I?

So,

```
List1 = "1, 2, 3, 4"
List2 = "a, b, c, d"
```

If I convert these to arrays, how do I bind them to a `Repeater` and get the values of each list within the `Repeater`?

I want to get an HTML output that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <span> CONTENT TO LIST 1(0) </span>
    <span> CONTENT OF LIST 2(0) </span>
</div>

<div>
    <span> CONTENT TO LIST 1(1) </span>
    <span> CONTENT OF LIST 2(1) </span>
</div>
.... etc
```

Comment: Whoa your question has been editted to something completely diff... you should just make a new question. Now my answer which answered your first question exactly makes no sense at all...

Comment: Sorry... I know! I changed my mind about how to do it... still.. answers to both questions still relevant, I'm kinda having troubles working out how to approach this!

Comment: where is the output of `List2` in your question?  You can just merge the lists into a single `List` with a custom object and then just bind to the new `List`.

Comment: It's OK... I *think* your first example is doing it for me. It's a bit long winded in VB as opposed to the C# you posted though.

Comment: Cool, glad it is working.  The VB should be almost the same minus the `;` :)

Comment: I had the totally wrong approach... fixed it now by making a  datatable... but you're answer kinda helped!! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, here is a simple example.

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpTest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="row<%# Eval("ID").ToString() %>">DIV CONTENT</div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Prep Test Code:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

In your Page_Load or where you initialize the `Repeater`:

```
List<TestObject> lst = new List<TestObject>();
lst.Add(new TestObject() { ID = 0, Text = "Zero" });
lst.Add(new TestObject() { ID = 1, Text = "One" });
lst.Add(new TestObject() { ID = 2, Text = "Two" });
lst.Add(new TestObject() { ID = 3, Text = "Three" });

rpTest.DataSource = lst;
rpTest.DataBind();
```

Output:

```
<div id="row0">DIV CONTENT</div>     
<div id="row1">DIV CONTENT</div>     
<div id="row2">DIV CONTENT</div>    
<div id="row3">DIV CONTENT</div>
```

**EDIT:**

To bind to an `Array` just assign the `Array` to the `DataSource` and then access the `Array` items in your binding with:

```
<%# Container.DataItem %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion the aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div>
                <span>CONTENT TO LIST 1(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Key").ToString()%>)</span>
                <span>CONTENT TO LIST 2(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Value").ToString()%>)</span>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The code behind:

```
Dim test() As String = "1,2,3,4".Split(",")
Dim test2() As String = "a,b,c,d".Split(",")

Dim ls As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))
For i As Integer = 0 To test.Count - 1
    ls.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(test(i), test2(i)))
Next
rep.DataSource = ls
rep.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0):

in .net webforms you could use

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < totalRequired; i++)
   { %>
   <div id="<%= i %>"></div>
<% } %>
```

Hope that helps.